# The electric field at the bisector of a uniformly charged half-sphere made of dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

While solving this problem, we arrived at the solution in a form of discontinuous function of electric field. Intuitively it doesn't seem right. What is a physics explanation behind this discontinuity? Or is the mathematical approach wrong? Or is it just so idealised problem that it doesn't exist in reality anyway, so discontinuity doesn't have any physics meaning?
Tried solution (electric field as sum of electric fields of all thin rings):
[image]
[image]

Comment: This does seem somewhat wrong, but discontinuous E fields are great approximations to some physically relevant scenarios, particularly involving conductors. This seems like a dielectric problem and should probably not have such discontinuity.